# How to load the current viewcontroller when application comes to foreground

Tags: ios

I want to keep the current viewcontroller to load when the application came back to foreground from the background when the user clicks the home button. How I can do that.. every time when I press the home btn and again touch the app icon it loads at the beginning with the splash screen, how to avoid this

Thanks

Comment: You question is somehow confusing. What do you mean by "everytime when I press the home btn and again touch the app icon it loads at the begining with the splash screen"? Your app starts from the beginning, or it just shows the splash screen?

Comment: yes my app start from the begining,,,, once I open the app  then press the home btn,, again open the app it start from the begining

Comment: Then, your app is crashing when home button is pressed. Check your app for the exceptions, and post the crash logs so that we could help you.

Comment: @FahriAzimov's diagnosis is the most probable problem with your app.

On the off chance it is not, check in your `appDelegate` methods check the app state change methods mentioned in [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillEnterForeground:)

Comment: Has the application being built by you from scratch? or is it being copied from somewhere?

Comment: I built from the scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you set variable in info.plist file `NO`
[image]

Comment: - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application is called when you press home button right ?

Comment: I have previaousely set the appliction doesnot run in background to YES,, now I set it to NO but it gives me an error like this Couldn't register com.microimage.Thala-Live with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.(lldb)

Comment: remove derived data and restart pc and reset simulator may be you sucess

Comment: Im running this in the device,, what is the derive data and how to remove those

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38394/discussion-between-idia-and-kirti-mali)